# Creating and Accessing beans in blueprint

Tags: javabeans, blueprint-osgi

Im creating a bean in blueprint xml like below

```
<bean id="myDao" class="com.MyDAO"></bean>
```

I want to access it from a java file which will be maven built as an osgi container and deployed in servicemix.

How to create such beans and access it inside a java file?

Comment: Are you starting any services or just want to access the bean. Former is the preferred way in OSGI. I guess there might be helper APIs for latter. Please check [OSGI java doc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/overview-summary.html)